# What value does a substring have if it doesn't exist?

Tags: javascript, substring

I have a string, `msg`. I want to check if the third character in the string exists or not.
I've tried `if (msg.substring(3, 4) == undefined) { ... }` but this doesn't work. What would the substring be equal to if it does not exist?

Comment: Have you tried `msg.length >= 3` ?

Comment: This is answered by the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring#description)

Comment: @RayToal I will try that now

Comment: @Amy Sorry, I tried looking on the documentation but I didn't know how to phrase it

Comment: @RayToal thanks very much! please could you put that in an answer so that I can mark the question as answered?

Comment: Happy to, just did, along with the usual "character indexing is hard" caveat :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third character of the string exists if the string has three characters, so the check you are looking for is

```
msg.length >= 3
```

As to your question about a non-existent substring, you get the empty string, which you can test in a console:

```
> "dog".substring(8, 13)
''
```

It's generally worth a mention that indexing and taking the length of characters is fraught with Unicode-related difficulties, because what JavaScript thinks of as a character is not really a character, but a UTF-16 character code. So watch out for:

```
> "".length
4
> ""[1]
'�'
> ""[2]
'�'
> [...""][1]
''
```

So if you are looking for better characters do:

```
[...msg].length >= 3
```

That will still not work with Unicode grapheme clusters, but it is at least better than taking the actual length of string, which is broken in JavaScript (unless you are dealing with what they call BMP characters).

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

```
Any argument value that is less than 0 or greater than stringName.length is treated as if it were 0 and stringName.length, respectively.
```

This isn't super intuitive but your example will be an empty string `""` (or if the first position has a character and you've added a larger gap, it will be a string that is shorter than the space between indexStart and indexEnd:

```
const str = 'hi';
console.log(str.substring(1, 4)); // is "i"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take a standard [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) for getting a character or `undefined`.

```js
const
    string0 = '',
    string1 = 'a',
    string2 = 'ab',
    string3 = 'abc',
    string4 = 'abcd';

console.log(string0[2]); // undefined
console.log(string1[2]); // undefined
console.log(string2[2]); // undefined
console.log(string3[2]); // c
console.log(string4[2]); // c
```

Answer (score -2):

If string doesn't contains enough letters substrings doesn't returns nothing. You can try use string as array which return undefined if index doesn't exist.

```js
if ( msg[2] !== undefined ) {}
```

Comment: Please try to avoid code-only answers, even if the question might be simple. "Try this", with some code slapped after it, is not a good way to explain/understand something after all.

Comment: I hope now is better :)